# Creating thumbnails for images on S3

Tags: pdf, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have quite common situation, as I suppose. I have website that is lcoated on amazon EC2 and I'd like to move all dynamic files to amazon S3. Everything seems ok, except 2 points:

1. I'm using library [PDFNet](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/) with their [WebViewer](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/index.html). To display pdf files in browser Webviwer use special ".xod" format. PDFNet provide functionality to convert pdf files to xod format. Let's see an example, when PDF file was upload on S3 and no xod file was created (I'm going to use Lambda to avoid it in future, but still). So in this case I have to download file to my local machine, convert it to xod file and upload xod file on S3(I don't see any other opportunities to do it, but it can take a lot of traffic)?
2. Second problem is almost the same, but it's linked with thumbnails. Currently I'm dynamically resize thumbnails depending on the required resolution and I'd like to keep it. Amazon Lambda is not situable in this case, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you say that Lambda is not suitable here?

For pt#1 PDFNet gives a library for Java, you can write a lambda function in java (its possible now) and use that to get infinite scale.

For pt#2: Amazons tutorial (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) gives a detailed example of how to resize images when uploaded to S3. The example is in nodeJs, you can write a java version as well if you like.

Note that if you want to have custom logic for decision making, you can add attributes while uploading the file in S3 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#User-Defined Metadata) which you can use in your lambda function to take decisions while resizing.

Comment: Actually my problem was: how to create thumbnail for image, which is already on amazon? Is there is any way except downloading file, craeting thumbnail and uploading thumbnail. But I think it's not required anymore, thanks.

Comment: Any examples about how to create pdf thumbnails using PDFNet that I can use in lambda? Thanks in advance.

Comment: PDFNet currently does not support .Net core and hence, cannot be used in Lambda which only supports .Net core. AWS Lambda runs on Linux containers.

Comment: Just to add something: Although PDFNet supports python, I believe it doesn't support the Linux platform and hence cannot run.